# What is the proper way to activate VGs/LVs automatically on boot?

Tags: busybox, lvm, buildroot

I have used [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) to create a system that runs in RAM on my ARMv5 Kirkwood SoC -based NAS-box. I use [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) as my init system, and `/dev` management is done using devtmpfs only. I've selected LVM2 & device mapper -target package, with standard install instead of only dmsetup. I configured the Linux kernel to have multiple devices driver support with device mapper support. System boots up without any problems, but logical volumes are inactive. If I execute `vgchange -ay` they are activated and can be mounted.

My question is, what is the proper way of automatically activating volumes during boot? Is there some configuration option for that? Or do I really need to execute `vgchange -ay` at some point during boot (e.g. `/etc/inittab`)? [Some sources seem to suggest that VGs/LVs are usually automatically activated on boot](http://emidio.planamente.ch/docs/linux/lvm-html/linuxdoc/lvm-5.html#ss5.4), but I'm unsure if they are just referring to implementations of initialization process on popular distributions.

Comment: As far as I know the initrd creation script on most popular distributions does the VG activation when there is an LVM root device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something has to run the LVM utility (as you say, `vgchange -a y` or similar) at some point. There is no magic that makes the kernel figure that one out by itself.

In Initramfs this is usually done by the `/init` script (directly or indirectly). Some systems also scan for VG/LV whenever `udev` gets told of a new disk, but with devtmpfs you don't have that option either.

So yes sure, just make an init script for LVM and have your init system execute it somehow.

Comment: Ok... At first that seemed like unnecessarily complicated, but now when I look at it again, I guess it's just as simple as is practical. Thanks for your answer!